# I am using laravel livewire 3 get page not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

when click I get page not found and in consle
error : POST http://localhost/livewire/update 404 (Not Found)

counter.blade.php

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ $this->count }}</h1>

    <button wire:click="increment">+</button>

    <button wire:click="decrement">-</button>
</div>
```

in blade I have the following :

```
@section('custom-js')
     @livewireScripts
@endsection

@section('custom-css')
    @livewireStyles
@endsection


<livewire:counter />
```

when click on increment or decrement I get page not found

Comment: Could you please share the routes you see on `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Livewire3**,  then no need to inject css & javascript of livewire assets manualy, because they are automaticaly injected.

check this [documentation page](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart#create-a-template-layout) to see.

Answer (score 0):

You must create livewire component first

```
php artisan make:livewire CreatePost
```

an update function into Livewire component.

```
public function update(){...}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).